# Best practice to go:embed assets up the file tree?

Tags: go

My project is currently structured such that the HTML templates are in the root of the project within a `templates/` directory.

My HTTP request handlers are several levels down the file system tree.

```
go.mod
templates/webpp/*.html
templates/admin-dashboard/*html
cmd/webapp/main.go
cmd/admin-dashboard/main.go
app/webapp/handlers/handler.go
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to use go:embed in the following way:

```golang
//go:embed ../../templates
```

or

```golang
///go:embed $PROJECT_ROOT/templates
```

But unfortunately neither of these methodologies exist. The `go doc embed` says:

> The patterns are interpreted relative to the package
> directory containing the source file. The path separator is a forward slash,
> even on Windows systems. Patterns may not contain ‘.’ or ‘..’ or empty path
> elements, nor may they begin or end with a slash.

I could relocate the templates (something I'd rather not do since in some modes my webapp expects to see them relative to the running binary). e.g.

```
webapp            <-- binary uses templates at runtime
templates/*.html  <-- editable HTML files
```

So I could have my build script copy them in place just before compilation, but this seem unnecessarily convoluted; if I bypasses the build script or forget or mess up the build sequence, I could end up with a v2 binary with v1 "old templates" embedded.

Or, I could make the `templates/` directory into a package and export an `embed.FS` and then inject it as a dependency to my application, but now my code is re-structured just to accomodate the embedding process.

Is there any likelyhood that go:embed will allow some type of embedding relative to the project root in future, or would this raise security issues?

go:embed is a great feature, but it feels like I'm beholden to it- either forced to copy, relocate, split up my sets of templates into separate directories or adjust my application to use dependency injection.

What's the best practice?

Comment: Your templates folder should exist within a go package, and that package should embed the folder to an exported variable.  If other packages need to access those files, they should import that original package to access them

Comment: It's also not clear why moving the `go:embed` instruction into the template directory leads to dependency injection. You'd use it the exact same way. All that changes is that you add one additional import statement and that the FS value is now package qualified.

Comment: `What's the best practice?` To keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Hymns for Disco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11424673/hymns-for-disco) you may wish to make `templates` a module by adding a go file within the directory to abstract access to your templates and use the `//go:embed: *html` syntax. Alternatively you could move the actual templates down a level and use `//go:embed templates`.

Unfortunately the recent Go blog post ["Organizing a Go module"](https://go.dev/doc/modules/layout) doesn't really deal with supporting files, but some might argue that the "right" way to do this is to make a package in `/internal` called, say, `/internal/fs` and your templates would be in `/internal/fs/templates`.

I'll continue with an example in a directory below the top of the project called `/web`. This approach is intended to files off disk in development mode or from an embedded file system in production. The structure as follows:

```
    ./web
    ├── fs.go
    ├── fs_test.go
    ├── static
    │   ├── favicon.svg
    │   ├── htmx.min.js
    │   └── hyperscript.js
    └── templates
        ├── home.html
        └── partial-report.html
```

fs.go can embed the files something like this:

```golang
//go:embed templates
var templatesFS embed.FS

//go:embed static
var StaticFS embed.FS
```

One can then either use the embedded file systems or swap these out for direct access to the file system using `os.DirFS`. However, one oddity I've found is that they mount at different levels. Embedded mode mounts "static" at `.` while `os.DirFS` mounts it at `./static/`, for example.

Using `fs.Sub(StaticFS, "static")` for the embedded mode allows both filesystem and embedded modes to be mounted at "static". See [timeaway](https://github.com/rorycl/timeaway/blob/a33d280499c9de5b7b670261c2b55b5973767029/web/fs.go#L28) for an example.

Comment: We still should be allowed to point to whatever path we want. I end up placing my resources directory at the same level as main.go, then pass around the `embed.FS`.